# Onclick of table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am building a html5 Phone app using Cordova and in several pages I am using a table to act as a button. In every page but one this is working without issue but on one page the onclick event will not fire

Here is the HTML of the table

```
<div id="buttonHolder" class="MiniButtonGridHolder">
                <table id="AddButton" class="ButtonGrid" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p id="AddLink" class="clickableLinks">Add</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript Used to set the onlick event

```
function SetButton()
                {
                 console.log("next one");
                      var CurrentTable = document.getElementById("AddButton");

                      console.log($(CurrentTable).attr('id'));
                      CurrentTable.onclick = function () {
                          Console.log("set");
                          AddWorkItem();
                      };
                 console.log("NOW SET");
                }
```

The AddWorkItem function

```
function AddWorkItem()
                {
                    console.log("Started");
}
```

when I run this bit of code all the console.logs work except for the two that would execute when the button is clicked (IE Set and Started). The Jquery one even gets the correct table id.

I am sure the solution is something that will make me kick my self for not seeing it but at the moment I have spent about 3 hours trying to see where I have gone wrong with this and can't find anything.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong with this?

*EDIT*

I am calling this code here

```
     $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event,ui) {
    SetButton();

}
```

I have replicated the problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/p4bR9/2/

Comment: Few changes and Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nN22E/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `SetButton()` and it's `console` not `Console`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4bR9/1/)

Comment: Ahh the Console may be what's causes this not to work at all, just gonna go try that out now

Comment: Well I was hopeful that would solve the problem but it did not fix the issue

Comment: Then problem may be related to something else and not with above code block, as updated code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/p4bR9/1/

Comment: but this is pretty much the only javascript on the page. any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: May be because `$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event,ui) {` is not getting called and thus not running `SetButton();`, make sure `SetButton();` is running or called it on `document ready` for testing

Comment: SetButton() is defiantly running as the console.logs appear, I am in the process of stripping down the whole page to see what the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

Well, your button isn't clickable until the `onclick` event listener is added to it. And that isn't added until your `SetButton()` function is run. And in the code you posted, it doesn't get run.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    SetButton();
});
```

Comment: this is where I am running the code already, sorry for not pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#AddButton').on('click',function()
                   {
                       alert("check");
                   });
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/vbtWB/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood. But trying to change this

```
Console.log("set");
```

in

```
console.log("set");
```

and call in the table with event `onlick="SetButton();"`